# About this and self in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I know the "self" magic. But look at this snippet from nodejs(not complete).

```
Socket.prototype.connect = function(options, cb) {
......
  var self = this;
  var pipe = !!options.path;

  if (this.destroyed || !this._handle) {
    this._handle = pipe ? createPipe() : createTCP();
    initSocketHandle(this);
  }

  if (typeof cb === 'function') {
    self.once('connect', cb);
  }

  timers.active(this);

  self._connecting = true;
  self.writable = true;
......
}
```

It is my understanding that we must use self to create a closure. Here there is no closures in these lines but the author use both after assigning this to self. Does it make any difference here?

Comment: I assume it's used only because of convention and unity with the rest of the code. Using `this` in one place might just be an oversight.

Comment: since `self` is set to `this` they're the same variable. I'm not sure why the author mixes the two.

Answer (score 4):

In what you've shown in this particular code example, there is no reason to even have the `self` variable because there are no other function scopes that might need access to the original value of `this`.

Some developers have a consistent methodology or convention to create a local variable like `self` and assign it the value of `this` just so that they have it to use, if needed, in closures.  The `self` variable can also be minimized smaller than `this` because it can be renamed to a one character variable name, but `this` cannot be renamed.

In any case, the functionality here would not be affected if `self` was removed and only `this` was used in this particular method.

My own personal convention is to only define `self` if it is actually needed which is the same logic I use for other local variables and then I only use it inside the closure where it is needed.

Comment: The code is not complete. There are closures in this function. I just didn't post it. So the creation of self makes sense.

Comment: @AlvinCao - if there are anonymous callback functions defined inside this method and those callback functions want access to the original value of `this`, then yes this is a common design pattern to assign the value of `this` to a local variable which is often called `self` or `that` or `me` so that that local variable can be used inside the callback function to refer to the host object when `this` has a different value in the callback function.

Comment: Thank you, @jfriend00. But I'm afraid I'm not asking the convention of using a self variable. I know why. I'm asking in such non-closure code why the author use both words. I doubt if the author is complying to any convention to make the code clearer because I see code like this many times.

Comment: @AlvinCao - it is inconsistent and generally a bad practice to use `this` in part of the method and `self` in other parts of the method when `self` is not needed.  If you're going to use `self`, then use it everywhere or only when required in a closure, not sometimes but not others.  That's inconsistent and makes the code confusing and makes readers of the code wonder what's going on (when there is nothing going on).